# bash set -e has no effect

Tags: linux, bash

I want the bash application which sources the library to be killed if a library function fails.

I am told `set -e` does this.

lib.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

function die
{
    echo "dying: $1"
    exit 1
}

function get_info
{
    die "oops an error"
}
```

app.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

source "lib.sh"

echo "info: $(get_info)"

echo "ok"
```

Run it

```
$> bash app.sh
info: dying: oops an error
ok
```

`die` exited with 1 so `app.sh` with `set -e` should be killed too, right?

Why didn't this work?

Comment: Your script *would* exit if you did `info=$(get_info); echo "won't see this $info"`. Baffling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way you're using it is the confusing part.  The problem is that you aren't just calling `get_info`, you're using the result of that as part of another command (`echo` here).  That other command succeeds, and so the error condition never triggers the exit from bash.  You can see this if you extend your script a little:

```
echo "info: $(get_info)"
echo "ok"

v=$(get_info)
printf 'info2: %s\n' "$v"
printf 'ok2\n'
```

will never get to the `info2` print, because it exits during the variable assignment.

`set -e` is really tricky, an often is not recommended.  You can read more about it [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) and [here](http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Error_handling#Caveat_2:_.60Exit_on_error.27_not_exitting_subshell_on_error)

Comment: In a nutshell, what's the right way to implement my `die` function then? I tried `trap` but seems to have caveats in this situation too.

Comment: @spraff you'd have to actually check the values along the way, or do it in the different steps like I showed.  When you're running `die` in a subshell it cannot guarantee that it'll make the parent exit--well, unless it were to `kill` it's parent I guess, but I'm not sure that would work right if you're several shells down